# Event bus for NodeJS websocket servers

Tags: node.js, websocket, event-bus

I'm making an application in NodeJS that's using websockets. I would like to solve scaling issue by implementing an event bus between multiple instance of servers hidden, which are behind a load balancer (Nginx). I was thinking about Redis's PubSub as an event bus, but would like to know if there is any better solution for inter-process/server communication?